# missing 1 required positional argument when using self

Tags: python, python-3.x, positional-argument

I'm learning python. I have created a class visualizer which contains 2 methods. Now I want to call the first method inside my second method. I read I have to use self:

```
def method2(self):
    self.method1()
```

This works. Now I'm adding additional parameters:

```
def method2(self, param1, param2, param3):
    self.method1()
```

And I call it from my `main.py`:

```
xx.method2(param1, param2, param3)
```

Now I get an error:

```
missing 1 required positional argument: 'param3'
```

I checked, param3 is there and the sequence of parameters is the same. I think it's conflicting with `self`.

How can I solve this? Do I need an init method inside my class?

EDIT:
In my Main:

```
from project.visualizer import Visualizer
vsl = Visualizer

vsl.method2(param1, param2, param3)
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling the method of an instance not of the class. There are also class methods in Python.

Comment: What is `xx`? Is it an instance of your class? You need to provide a *compete* example: the class, how you create an instance of the class, and how you invoke the method(s).

Comment: No you don't need an `__init__`, but you _do_ need to create an instance of the class so you can call the method correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
vsl = Visualizer
```

This doesn't create an instance of `Visualizer` like you intend. As written it causes `vsl` to point to the `Visualizer` class rather than an *instance* of the class. When you call `vs1.method2()` it's as if you've written:

```
Visualizer.method2(param1, param2, param3)
```

It should be:

```
vsl = Visualizer()
```

If `Visualizer`'s constructor takes parameters, pass those in.

Answer (score 1):

To call method, you have initialize the class first.

```
x = Visualizer()
x.method2(...)
```